# Change attribute value for a specific node in XML using SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'd like to know how to update an XML attribute based on the value of another attribute?

In the following example, I'd like to set `b="321"` where `a="banana"`:

```
Declare @t table ( x xml )
insert into @t(x) values ('<n1><n2 a="apple" b="2" /><n2 a="banana" b="21" /></n1>')
```

This select works well to extract the desired value, but how can it be modified?

```
select m.n.value('@b', 'int') from @t 
  outer apply x.nodes('/n1/n2') as m(n)
  where m.n.value('@a', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'banana'
```

This update does nothing...

```
update @t
  set x.modify('replace value of (/n1/n2/@b)[1] with "321"')
  where x.value('(n1/n2/@b)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'banana'

select * from @t
```

This update changes the first node, which isn't the desired result

```
update @t
  set x.modify
  (
    'replace value of (/n1/n2/@b)[1] with
    (
      if ( (/n1/n2/@a)[1] = "banana" ) then "321"
      else "?help"
    )'
  )

select * from @t
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
Declare @t table ( x xml )
insert into @t(x) values ('<n1><n2 a="apple" b="2" /><n2 a="banana" b="21" /></n1>');

UPDATE @t SET x.modify('replace value of (/n1/n2[@a="banana"]/@b)[1] with "321"');

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

The idea in short:

You must tell what you want to replace. In this case the value of the attribute `@b` in the `<n1>`-element, where the attribute `@a` is "banana". This needs a predicate in the `XPath`. You read it like:

*Find a n1 and below a n2, check for one with an attribute `a` which is "banana". Yeah, you've found one? Great! No take the attribute `b` of the first occurance and change it.